# Getting 401 Client Error when using firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase and I'm trying to update some data in an existing project but I'm getting the following error: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url. So how to fix this problem and thank you! I just want to mention also that I have been added to the project, so I'm not the owner.
this is my code:

```
from firebase import firebase

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication("the http path", None) # None bcz we are testing

firebase.put("/esco-lebanon/device-configs/atest-dev", "brightness", 50)

print("Updated")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-error-conditions), a 401 error means one of the following:

> - The auth token has expired.
> - The auth token used in the request is invalid.
> - Authenticating with an access_token failed.
> - The request violates your Firebase Realtime Database Rules.

The understanding here is that your client code needs to correctly identify a Firebase Authentication user with a token in [access_token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-param-auth), and that user account must have access to read the data in the database according to its security rules.  Since you haven't provided a token, your access is coming in anonymously, so you could only query data where security rules allow universal access.

If you haven't investigated using authentication in your request, you should [read the documentation about that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth).

Comment: I read the documentation, I must generate a new private key, however, I don't have the service accounts tab in the Firebase console to do that!